# wifi and vlans problems

Tags: vlan, wireless

I was given the task to come up with network design to change the existing one that we have since we are running a single network in the company with no VLANs in place to separate de departments. 
On our test environment, I created the network with 4 VLAN Groups and it worked fine with all the laptops connected directly to the switch they don't see the other departments. the only problem I came across was when the go on wifi they all start to see each other.
My question is can the VLANs be applied to the wifi access point also using the same SSID?

the wifi only has the corp and guest  SSID's

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No you are not able to access multiple vlans using single WIFI connection. But your WIFI connection can be one VLAN in your network and Other VLANs can allocate for Wired network.

You can Implement Wireless VLANs. It is allowed to access Multiple VLANs with Multiple SSIDs. That mean, each VLAN should have single and Separate SSID.

[Reference](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/wireless/software/guide/wireless_vlans.html)

Comment: You can use a single SSID, *if* you use another method of identifying users, such as 802.1x.  But that may be more complicated (and expensive) than you want.

Comment: @RonTrunk you mean, CISCO ISE technology with Profiling. am i correct?

Comment: That is one option, yes.

Comment: @RonTrunk could please explore any other options if you know. It will be valuable for future use

Comment: You could mange it with a simpler RADIUS server as well.

Comment: @RonTrunk and Infra  thank you for taking the time to answer .

Comment: so based on your answers there is no easy way of accomplishing this unless they spend more or for me to use multiple SSID

Comment: @Brain Yes. You are correct

Comment: @Brain It does not mean, You cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you associate each WLAN SSID with a (wired) VLAN. So essentially, you create a new SSID for each new VLAN, associate it to the VLAN and you're set.